# Aggregate Output of Script

Tags: linux, shell, awk

So, I'm a bit lost here.

I'm trying to detect the presence of iBeacons.

I have a script which puts out data like this:

```
F992A0DE-5A63-4BC1-80F9-5F47A53A0C31 1 1 -60 -55 1.09090 1.87003
```

I can control the output so if necessary I can add semicolons or something like that.

The problem is: I need the output of the script aggregated.
The first field represents the UID of the beacon that is detected.

I want to always take 20 lines of every UID that appears, aggregate the 4th value and so get a average.
If this average is over a value a http request should be sent.

I have really no idea how to move on.
Would it be better to push the output to a file first?
I found a few threads and think I could accomplish this with awk, is this the right way?

Comment: `The first field represents the UID of the beacon` : What do you mean by first field here, the first field separated by `-` or by space ` ` ?   Also, show us the input and output

Comment: sorry, by first field i mean this: "F992A0DE-5A63-4BC1-80F9-5F47A53A0C31" the parts are separated by a space

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!

something like this?  not tested.

```
awk -v threshold=$th 'c[$1]<20 {s[$1]+=$4; c[$1]++}
                      END      {for(k in a) 
                                  {avg = s[$1]/c[$1];
                                   if(avg>threshold) print k,a[k]}}' file
```

set the required threshold (here assumed to be in variable `$th`)